# Yesod: Handling session data within simple project

Tags: haskell, github, oauth, oauth-2.0, yesod

I'm looking to authenticate a user using GitHub as an oauth2 endpoint and get some session data.

I've got the whole authentication working but I want to be able to get some more useful info from the session beyond the user ID such as the session token for instance so I can make GitHub API calls on their behalf.

I'm ignorant to how and instance of YesodAuth can be manipulated and how the whole plugin architecture works within Yesod so any advice there would be awesome.

Here's where I'm at right now:

**Foundation.hs**

```
instance YesodAuth App where
  type AuthId App = Text
  getAuthId = return . Just . credsIdent

  loginDest _ = HomeR
  logoutDest _ = HomeR

  authPlugins _ =
    [ -- authBrowserId def,
      oauth2Github clientId clientSecret
    ]

  authHttpManager = appHttpManager

  -- Session functions here
  -- ???
  maybeAuthId = lookupSession "_ID"
```

**Home.hs**

```
getHomeR :: Handler Html 
getHomeR = do
    --(formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost sampleForm
    --let submission = Nothing :: Maybe FileForm
    --    handlerName = "getHomeR" :: Text

    maid <- maybeAuthId

    -- Getting nothing for all of these
    sess <- getSession
    let access_token = lookup "access_token" sess
        user_name = lookup "login" sess
```

[Link to my project code](https://github.com/StarStuffSteve/CS7009)

Comment: Can you see what is in the session "_ID" ? That is likely to contain "access_token" information serialized within it.

Comment: Its the GitHub user ID, no token. It gets returned in the session at present along with nothing else. I figure there is someway of configuring YesodAuth to return more in the session but I've yet to find a way.